# Groups and Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

I was reading a book about Catalan Numbers (Thomas Koshy Catalan numbers with applications)

And I was reading through that example.

> Find the number of n-element multisets  $\{a_1 ,a _2 , . . . , a_n \}$
>   of elements $a_i \in Z_{n+1}$ such that $a_1 + a_2 + . . . + a_n = 0$,
>   the additive identity of $Z_{n+1}$ .

So it is believed this example generates the Catalan numbers sequence.

But I disagree with the table he provides .

[image]

So when $n=1$ we have that $Z_{n+1} = Z_{2}$ and so we should have that $1 + 1 = 0 + 0 = 0$ and so the count should be 2 not 1

and for the case where $n=0$ which is not inlcuded in the above table, it should be $1$ because we only have $0 + 0 = 0$

and so the sequence should be $$1,2,2,5,14,...$$

Did I do something wrong here ?

Comment: When $n=1$ you want to consider $1$-element multisets, so $0$ is the only possibility.

Comment: but in the table he uses $0,1$  for the case where $n=1$

Comment: He's just listing the elements of $Z_{n+1}$. If you go back and read the discussion, he talks about taking $n$-element subsets of $Z_{n+1}$.

Comment: hahahaha @rogerl I am so dumb lol thanks a lot

Comment: but why did he put anything besides $n=1$, So he means $0+0$ right ?

Comment: Well,  no. He means just 0. It's a one element multiset summing to 0 where the elements come from 0, 1.